Issue running AWS Fargate with Next.js and Libreoffice
I'm attempting to convert an Excel file to a PDF using Next.js. When I run the script, I receive an error in my Cloudwatch that says that the soffice bin is not found. The which command in the dockerfile returns /usr/bin/soffice at build stage (which as I understand is correct).
Does anyone have any advice here?
TIA
I have the following Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat bash \
    && apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted \
    libreoffice libreoffice-common libreoffice-calc libreoffice-writer openjdk8-jre
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
    if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
    elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
    elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
    else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
    fi
ENV PATH="/usr/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN which soffice

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
ENV NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE true
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN \
    if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
    elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
    elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
    else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
    fi

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0" node server.js


Does the docker image work when you run it locally? This seems like a docker image issue, and it is the type of thing you should test and get working locally first before even trying to deploy it to AWS.
